# Tubing for explosive gas or hydrogen transfer

Tags: pressure, safety, compressed-air, pressure-vessel

Recently, I heard that there is a law/ OSHA/ ASME piece of regulation dictating that hydrogen should be transferred (suppose from a tank of hydrogen to another location) by using specially approved tubing. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it is true and for that case there will be many relevant codes / regulations that need to be respected. Make sure you read them all before designing / altering the system.

Comment: Although this doesn't include any supporting information, I have to agree that it is more likely than not the case, just based off the situation.  Often hydrogen is stored in some sort of pressurized container.  Already you need to make sure that the pressure can be safely contained and discharged.  The bigger point is the flammability of hydrogen.  If hydrogen meets with enough oxygen it will combust, and any ignition sources would be extremely dangerous.  [Some info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_safety).  You likely need approved tubing and connections and precautions in the area.

Comment: Could anyone direct me to a source in the literature on the matter? I was able to find this: Safety Alert – Improper Tubing for Flammable Gases from Arizona State University       I guess that if that is how they say it should be handled, it kind of answers the question in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex topic, if you are responsible for designing/altering such a system, I would say you should consult an expert in hydrogen transport. You will need input on the appropriate materials for the pipe (e.g. MOC of pipe for hydrogen embrittlement) and the types of joints required at the minimum.

Starting reading regarding the MECHANICAL design of hydrogen piping (note the scope) - 
NFPA 50A: Standard for Gaseous Hydrogen Systems at Consumer Sites, 1999 Edition

On the PROCESS design for hydrogen usage, it would be the same as any other gas transport application, using the appropriate materials and developing the proper process parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question pertains to smaller quantities as may be used in a laboratory or specialized heat-treating : H can easily be handled with ordinary materials = carbon steel, copper and stainless steel. A major concern with H is that if there is any leakage it will rise and collect at the top of any enclosure. So design needs to include things like  explosion proof/ gas tight light fixtures.

Comment: I know that there are many materials that can be used to transport hydrogen gas, but I was asking with regard to existing regulations about what material a tube must be made of to transport the hydrogen legally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have used regular acrylic tubing for the gaseous state. However, if any spark contact may occur, use spark resistors, a bubbler, ect. If it is in liquid state I would assume that more would be required. My project this year used hydrogen as a fuel source produced through electrolysis that was run through solar energy. My hydrogen output was in a gaseous state for efficiency.